# Aren't "local geography" topics missing in the Help Center?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope

I had a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and I could not find anything about local geography. These would be questions such as

- is there a walking path between X and Y in city Z?
- is the 16 district (*16<sup>ème</sup> arrondissement*) a no-go zone in Paris because of the inherent danger there?
- can I bring my dog to park X in city Y?

There are plenty of questions on these topics; many very interesting - my point is that whether they are welcome or not is not addressed in the Help Center (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now updated, thanks for the suggestion